# python sqlite3 - Why are parameter markers not working for columns?

Tags: python, sqlite

Being a bleeding python and sqlite beginner stumbling into the extremely weird behavior when trying to substitute a column-name with a variable like so:

```
c.execute('SELECT ? FROM table', ("columnA",))
```

just led me on a wild goose chase until I finally figured out that you can only use parameter markers to substitute value-names...not column-names.

Now of course I'm wondering why that is and if:

```
c.execute("SELECT %s FROM table" % (data))
```

truly is the best way to go about this - what with all the sqlinjection nonsense, and whatnot.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Table and column names have to be known when the statement is compiled; they can't be parameters.

Comment: But the second example works. Doesn't the statement here get assembled during runtime as well when the %s is being substituted with the content of the 'data' variable?

Comment: No. That's string substitution that's done before the execute function is even called

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Shawn , I obviously have some reading up to do...
Do you want to put your first comment as the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

**Table** and **column names** have to be known when the statement is compiled; they can't be parameters.
The second code snippet above works, as the string substitution in it is done before the execute function is being called.